# Cut date from String

Tags: java, string, date

I wrote a little app to cut a correct date from String. When I have a string, lets say, "2007-01-12sth" it works ok, it prints "2007-01-12". When I have a string "txt2008-01-03" its not ok ... I think that the best way to explain this is to paste my whole code:

```
public class test
{
    public static boolean isValid(String text) {
        if (text == null || !text.matches("\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d"))
            return false;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        df.setLenient(false);
        try {
            df.parse(text);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // txt2008-01-03 is NOT ok INCORRECT, should print 2008-01-03
        // 2007-01-12sth is ok CORRECT 
        // 20999-11-11 is is NOT ok CORRECT 

        String date = "txt2008-01-03";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(date);

        if(m.find())
            date = date.substring(0, m.end());

        if(isValid(date))
            System.out.println(date + " ");
    }

}
```

How can I cut date from both "txt2008-01-03" AND "2007-01-12sth"? (Not only from "2007-01-12sth")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the way you grab the date:

```
if(m.find())
    date = date.substring(0, m.end());
```

Just grab what the matcher found:

```
if (m.find())
    date = m.group();
```

However there is still a problem: with `20999-11-11` your regex will extract `0999-11-11` (maybe your initial code was made to account for this?). Replace your regex with this:

```
// A date, as long as it is NOT preceded/followed by a digit
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d(?!\\d)");
```

`(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind: "find a position where what is before does not match `...`".

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead: "find a position where what follows does not match `...`".

They have positive versions: `(?<=...)`, `(?=...)`.

Comment: +1. `m.group()` is the best solution. He also could have replaced the `0` with `m.start()`.